# MVC3: Set Dropdown list Selected Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I am using mvc3 and I have a drop down list in my view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,
new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text"))
```

Is there a way of setting the selected value in the View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending on what Romias said, in your controller, set Model.State to whatever value you want. If you wanted 'WI', then Model.State should equal that.

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var m = new TestViewModel();
    m.State = "WI";
    return View(m);
}
```

**View**:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text", Model.State))
```

Comment: Is it possible to set this value in the view instead?

Comment: It is, by why would you want to? It's bad practice.

Comment: Hi @rudeovski ze bear,

It's works for me. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text", Model.State))
```

Comment: May be he meant "using javacript"... but lets wait for him to update the question or something.